# color change of navigation buttons when scrolling up and when scrolling down

Tags: css, angularjs, plugins, navigation

I am using [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) to hide my header when scrolling down and make my header section visible again when scrolling up. The header section contains my logo and navigation buttons.

While at the top of my page I need my navigation buttons to be a darker color because my background color is a lighter, and when scrolling down i need my navigation buttons to be a lighter color because the header background color is darker.

I have created colors classes in CSS to change the button colors.

CSS:

```
.topColor {color: red;}

.scrollColor {color: white;}
```

I'm using angularjs for this project, so i'm using headroom.js angular module and the option below.

angular:

```
<headroom id="header" tolerance="5" offset="205" classes='{"initial":"animated","pinned":"swingInX","unpinned":"swingOutX","top":"headroom--top","notTop":"headroom--not-top"}' >
```

In an attempt to accomplish the task of changing my navigation buttons, I tried two different approaches.

1.) Created a directive to check if headroom hasClas('headroom--not-top') and if it did add class ('.scrollColor') to my navigation buttons ('#navColor') otherwise add class ('.topColor').

```
.directive('headroom', function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            if($(element).hasClass('headroom--not-top'))
            {
                $('#navColor').addClass('.scrollColor');
            }else{
               $('#navColor').addClass('.topColor');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

2.) I then tried this approach...

```
.directive('headroom', function(){
        return{
            restrict:'E',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                if($(element).hasClass('headroom--not-top'))
                {
                    $scope.myNavColor = "scrollColor";
                }else{
                    $scope.myNavColor = "topColor";
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

nav in html

```
<li><a id="navColor" ng-class="{current: isCurrentPath('/')}"  active class = "{{myNavColor}}"  ng-href="#/">Home</a></li>
```

Neither attempt worked for me, however the first attempt did change the button white, but when i scrolled down it did not change. I believe the problem is $(element) is not being recognized, or am I just approaching this task completely wrong?

Comment: your using restrict "A" but you are using the directive as restrict "E".

Comment: @dowomenfart I've changed the restrict to "E" but it still doesn't want to work for me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no console errors. The headroom class attribute is different from the standard, it uses classes. Do you think that may be causing the problem? 'code' <headroom id="header" tolerance="5" offset="205" classes='{"initial":"animated","pinned":"flipInX","unpinned":"flipOutX","top":"headroom--top","notTop":"headroom--not-top"}' >

Comment: Just wondering can you recreate this in a jsfiddle or a plunkr? Would really appreciate to see this code in action.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this "issue" using CSS! headroom.js uses two classes to detect when the header is at top the page and when it's scrolling (not a the top), so I provided the following CSS.

```
header.headroom--not-top ul li a{
    color: red;
}

header.headroom--top ul li a{
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using nav class from bootstrap):

```
nav.headroom--not-top  { color: red; background-color: lightgrey; opacity: .8 }
nav.headroom--top  { color: white }
```

It work, but the ideal situation would be that the color was a complementary color from the background color when the nabber descend.. Isn't?. Maybe in jQuery...