# How to change the color of a button using AngularJS directive when scrolling bar reaches at a certain height

Tags: angularjs, button, colors, scrollbar, directive

Hi I am new to AngularJS, I want to use an AngularJS directive to change the color of the button when the scroll bar is moved and it reaches at a certain height, any detailed answer and help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can find your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419895/color-change-of-navigation-buttons-when-scrolling-up-and-when-scrolling-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose initially color of your button is blue and when scroll bar reach to bottom of page, your button will turn green.

So here is the directive:

```
angular.module('newProjectApp')
.directive('myButton',function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template:
        '<button class="btn {{color}}" type="button" value="Submit">' +
        '</button>',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, $window) {
        scope.color ='primary-button';

        scope.$watch(function(){
        return $window.scrollY;
        }, function(){
          scope.color="success-btn";
        }, true);
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: @ Tanvee Gujral, thank you very much for a prompt response, I want to change the color of the button when the scroll bar is moved down e.g. 50 pixels from the top.

Comment: So just put if condition scope.$watch block, if($window.scrollY==50)

Comment: Thanks, I hope I will get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at angular-scroll-watch : https://github.com/pc035860/angular-scroll-watch.